# Hit-testing a UIGestureRecogniser in 3d space

Tags: ios, 3d, uigesturerecognizer, scenekit

I'm reasonably new to iOS's SceneKit and have come across a dilemma with regards to user-interaction in a 3d scene:

I have a set of `SCNNode` cubes in an `SCNView`, and would like to be able to pin-point where a user touches the mesh of a given cube, as a 3d coordinate (so as to later manipulate the scene according to touch vectors). At present, I've been using a `UIGestureRecognizer` in order to achieve basic hit-testing, but this *seems* to be limited to returning 2d-points.

This isn't a problem when wanting to hit-test a whole node itself, as this can be achieved via a `UIGestureRecognizer`'s hittest method in the `SCNView`. However, does anybody have any suggestions as to how to precisely locate where a touch landed on a node, in terms of coordinates (i.e. `SCNVector3`)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track with calling `hitTest:options:` on the `SCNView`. As you have probably seen it results in an array of `SCNHitTestResults`.

The hit test result can tell you many things about the hit, one of them being what node was hit. What you are looking for is either the `localCoordinates` or the `worldCoordinates`.

The *local* coordinate is relative to the node that was hit. Since you are asking "how to precisely locate where a touch landed on a node" this is probably the one you are looking for.

The *world* coordinate is relative to the root node.